# Specify url prefix for all openiddict routes

Tags: openiddict

I would like all openid functionality to be under a specific path (i.e. "idhub/connect/token"). I can specify urls per functionality but is it possible to configure openiddict to use a certain prefix for all routes? I'm unable to find it in the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in to support this scenario.

OpenIddict 3.0, when used with its ASP.NET Core or OWIN hosts, hooks itself in the request processing pipeline as an authentication handler/middleware, so you can also leverage things like `app.UsePathBase("/idhub")` in `Startup.Configure` to use a global path base for the entire app.

Comment: But don't want it for the entire app :), I´ll specifiy it for each route .